# c++ the difference between string using the assign function and directly using '=' to change the value

Tags: c++, c++11

For example, this code

```
std::string a("this is a string");
std::string b;
b = a;
std::string c;
c.assign(a);
```

Is there any difference between B and C in essence？

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34196053/stdstringassign-vs-stdstringoperator

Comment: Not really, the compiler will probably optimise away any differences

Comment: This is `assign(const char*)` not `assign(const string&)`.

Answer (score 2):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/assign)

> 2) `basic_string& assign( const basic_string& str );`
>
> ...
>
> 2) Replaces the contents with a copy of str. Equivalent to `*this = str`;. In particular, allocator propagation may take place. (since C++11)

So this does the same.

Comment: Is there any place where you must use assign？

Comment: There is absolutely no difference between `a = b;` and `a.assign(b);`, so there is no place, where you have to use it. If you have some stateful allocators, you may want to do `a.assign(b.c_str(), b.size());` to not copy the allocator, but for the standard allocator this is irrelevant.